# Find a word in a dictionary but a single letter was deleted from the word

Tags: algorithm, trie

I am trying to understand the following algorithm but I am having hard time on few things:

Firstly what does the input look like i.e. Aple or Ap_le and

Secondly what does this part of code do?

"We are adding the two possibilities: the first
        character has been deleted plus the first character is present
        `r=countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)`"

Thirdly shouldnt the second else if go through all the edegs linked to vertex?

Source:
https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/

```
countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters)
    k=firstCharacter(word)
    if isEmpty(word)
        return vertex.word
    else if notExists(edges[k]) and missingLetters=0
        return 0
    else if notExists(edges[k])
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word)
        return countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)
        Here we cut a character but we don't go lower in the tree
    else
        We are adding the two possibilities: the first
        character has been deleted plus the first character is present
        r=countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word)
        r=r+countWords(edges[k], word, missingLetters)
        return r
```

Comment: Just a little hint: The second ifelse will only call the countWords() at most 1 more time. This is because we cannot match the prefix anymore (no edges) but we can still check (by calling the countWords()) if removing one more letter will make a match. Meaning, if our word matched so far but we have an extra character at the end then we consider it a match (because we can remove it).

Comment: The code takes input like "aapple" or "appple" and sees if it can be made into a word by removing a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly : The Input is a vertex in the tree (the root) a word and a number of missing letters.

for example : countWords(rootNode,"apple",1)

Trees are inherently recursive and to understand these algorithms you should think of vertex as where you are starting on the tree for each subsequent call of the function.

Now I'm going to say in plain psudo-er code what each part of this logic does.

```
countWords(WhereYouAreAt, word, missingLetters)
    k = firstCharacter(word) # the first charactor is the next edge to traverse

    if(word = ""){Return(WhereYouAreAt.word)}

    else if (notExists(edges[k]) and missingLetters=0) {return 0} # Because you arn't at a word and and you can't make a word with the prefix that caused you to arrive at WhereYouAreAt.

    else if notExists(edges[k]){
         cutLeftmostCharacter(word)
         return countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)
         #use one of the missing letters on the current letter. continue from WhereYouAre
    }

    else{
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word) #!!!
        r=countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)
        r=r+countWords(edges[k], word, missingLetters) 
        return r
    }
```

Secondly the line cutLeftmostCharacter(word) #!!! needs to be before the line you are asking about which counts the number of words under the node WhereYouAreAt containing the letters in remaining in word minus some n missingLetters. This first line r= counts if you skip the first letter in word and r+= counts if you don't skip that letter.

The output is unfortunately still made worse by the fact that it may try and return the sum of a string and a number... to fix this we need to change the first if statement to

```
 if(word = ""){Return(vertex.words)}
```

rather than vertex.word ...

With this the output should be the number of words in the dictionary containing an ordered subset of the given letters from word.

I hope this helps.

Comment: just one question, is the input correct? I thought it was supposed to be missing a letter?

Comment: Yeah it is a number of missing letters, if you want to find words with a missing letter than you would have a condition where if(k == "_"): sum over all edges.

Comment: else if notExists(edges[k]) case: why you need to cut the left letter? if (notExists(edges[k])), that means the letter before k is missing right?